# how animate an UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to animate an `UIBarButtonItem` like the TheElements example project does.
I'm pretty sure I've to use the `customView` property but I don't want to use an image to be able to do that because I need to change titles with some Localized strings (multi language).
So is it possible to create a `UIButton` which looks like a `UIBarButtonItem` ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code.

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image0.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
        nil];

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"image0.png"]];
imageView.animationImages = images;

UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.bounds = self.imageView.bounds;
[button addSubview:self.imageView];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem * barButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: button] autorelease];
```

Some things to notice:

The `UIButton` is of zero area as it does not have its bounds set upon initialization, thus the bounds are initialized with the bounds of the `UIImageView` (which has its bounds initialized from the image).

The `UIButton` handles the action/target for the touch event. The `UIBarButtonItem`'s action/target are not set.

To animate:

```
[imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: Read my question to the end.. I have noticed that I don't want to use the UIImageView solution because I've to set some titles by Localized strings. So I want to know how can I create a UIBarButtonItem like with an UIButton for example

Answer (score 0):

For Swift-3.x
Create IBOutlet of `UIBarButtonItem` and implement `didSet` as follows

```
@IBOutlet weak var leftMenuBtn: UIBarButtonItem! {
        didSet {
            let icon = UIImage(named: "myCustomIcon")
            let iconSize = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: icon!.size)
            let iconButton = UIButton(frame: iconSize)
            iconButton.setBackgroundImage(icon, for: .normal)
            leftMenuBtn.customView = iconButton

            iconButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(leftMenuClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }
```

Then Implement selector method for above created left menu button

```
func leftMenuClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    /* Following is the code to animate ButtonView by rotation of 90 degrees,
 just replace with your own custom animation. */

    var transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.leftMenuBtn.customView!.transform = transform
    }
}
```